# How to write obj[var1][var2] = val in non-mutation way

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am designing a redux reducer where I came across a situation where I have to append nested form data. I am not able to think of a situation.

Statement that includes mutation is:

```
state[var1][var2] = val
```

How can we write this in non-mutation way so that it can be used in reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
return {
    ...state,
    var1: {
       ...state.var1,
       var2: val
    }
 };
```

Or you can use [`immer`](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer):

```
import produce from "immer";

let val = 5;
const state = { var1: { var2: 3 } };
const nextState = produce(state, draftState => {
    draftState.var2 = val;
})
```